# INSERT multiple values via join

Tags: postgresql, join, insert

I have three tables, representing two entities and a connection relationship. Each of the entity relations has an artificial surrogate key used for foreign key constraints in place of natural keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Group (
group_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
group_name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE GroupMember (
person_id INTEGER REFERENCES Person,
group_id INTEGER REFERENCES Group,
PRIMARY KEY (person_id, group_id)
);
```

I would like to insert multiple entries into the relationship relation `GroupMember`, but using the natural keys of the associated entities. Something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO GroupMember (person_id,group_id)
SELECT person_id,group_id
FROM Person P, Group G, (
('alice','girls'),
('bob','boys'),
('alice','coolkids'),
('bob','coolkids')
) AS X
WHERE P.username = X.1 AND G.group_name = X.2;
```

Obviously the above syntax isn't valid, but hopefully conveys the idea. Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [**`VALUES`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) expression to generate an ad-hoc table and join to the other tables to get the respective IDs.

```
INSERT INTO groupmember (person_id, group_id)
SELECT p.person_id, g.group_id
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('alice'::varchar, 'girls'::varchar)
   , ('bob','boys',
   , ('alice','coolkids')
   , ('bob','coolkids')
  ) x (username, group_name)
JOIN   person p  USING (username)
JOIN   "group" g USING (group_name);
```

Aside: don't use the reserved word `group` as table name.